# Shell script helper for git commits

Tags: git, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a simple shell script that simplifies the git commit process.

Instead of

```
git add . -A
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

I want to do `commit.sh "my commit message"`

Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
commit_message="$1"
git add . -A
git commit -m $commit_message
git push
```

There's two problems with this:

1. When the commit message includes spaces, like "my commit message", I get the following output:

   `error: pathspec 'commit' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

   `error: pathspec 'message' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

   So the only part of the commit message it uses is the "my" and the other parts "commit message" are left out.
2. I think `git add .` references the location of the shell script, not the current project directory. How do I make it so that `git add .` references where I currently am in the terminal?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You must quote the variable in your script.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
commit_message="$1"
git add . -A
git commit -m "$commit_message"
git push
```

I also set "-e" so that if there are any errors, the script will exit without processing subsequent commands.

As to your second question, the `.` in the script should refer to your current working directory, as you intend. However the `-A` is causing it to add all files that have been modiied in the repo.

Comment: 1) bash is not required for this script, sh would do the job just fine 2) bash is not necessarily found in `/bin`, it might be e.g. in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: I was merely copying what the OP wrote; you're right of course and I would normally use `/bin/sh` myself.

Answer (score 12):

You can create [alias with argument](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Advanced_aliases_with_arguments). Something like:

```
[alias]
  cap = "!git add . && git commit -m '$1' && git push origin"
```

Answer (score 5):

with and Alias I couldn`t put variables in the middle of the sentence, but you can create a function and put it on your .bashrc like this

```
commitpush(){
  git add --all . && git commit -m '$1' && git push origin '$2'
}
```

and use it like commitpush "commit description" branchname

Answer (score 1):

Been there, done that: [Git Flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow).

You can also [create aliases](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) in the git configuration file too. This is much better than writing shell scripts since these will be extensions of the `git` command itself.

Also, don't forget:

```
$ git commit --all
```

which will commit all files you added or edited with your commit.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution ,FYI

```
#!/bin/sh

comment=$1

git add ./*

git commit -m $comment

echo " commit finished,push to origin master  ? "

read commit

case $commit in 
y|Y|YES|yes)
git push
;;
n|NO|N|no)
 exit 0

esac
```

## usage

```
./commit.sh    your comment message ,type yes if you want to push to master
```

Comment: @iankit, how can you review this as No Action Needed?  It is desperately in need of an edit.

Comment: how does this improve the already accepted answer ? you are missing quotes around `$comment`. fwiw, if you `comment=$*` your script will be way easier to use (e.g. no need to quote the commit message when invoking `commit.sh`)

Comment: Tks a lot I'll  modify it in my project

Answer (score 0):

A while back I had similar idea and came with below file after doing some google searches for syntax.

Below script also adds a default message in case you do not care about commit message and reads current branch to push.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# get the argument message
message="$1"

# If no commit message is passed, use current date time in the commit message
if [[ -z "${message// }" ]]
    then
        message=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
fi

# stage all changes
git add .
echo "====staged all git files"

# add commit
git commit -m "$message"
echo "====added the commit with message: '$message'"

# get current branch and push
current_branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
git push origin "$current_branch"
echo "====pushed changes to '$current_branch' branch"
```